# Manuscript Formatting

Tags: publishing

What program should I use to actually lay out my manuscript? I am in Reedsy doing the editing and writing. The illustrator is working on the pictures, but I need to be working on the layout so I can drop in the covers, photos etc so I know if I need full page pictures, half page etc.

Comment: I've started looking into [Scribus](https://www.scribus.net/) but I haven't even figured out how to design longer pieces of text, though I think it should be able to do that. It feels like it has a bit of a steep learning curve but it's free and I made it work on a Mac though it had to be the 1.5 version. It's far from cut-paste-publish, though...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Isn't Reedsy a layout and design program? What do you want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is not clear. I am a newbie at all of this. All I have seen of Reedsy so far is run on word documentation- like WORD. I have not seen any ability to insert photos, choose a layout, select a format, design a front and back cover. Things like that are what I am seeking advise on.